# Data.Table Operation From One DataFrame to Another

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

```
dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    "w1"=c(2,2,0,2,1),
                    "w2"=c(2,0,0,2,1),
                    "w3"=c(2,2,0,2,1),
                    "w4"=c(1,0,0,1,2))


dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    "f1"=c(0,0,0,1,1),
                    "c1"=c(1,1,0,1,0),
                    "f2"=c(1,0,0,0,1),
                    "c2"=c(1,0,0,1,0),
                    "f3"=c(0,0,0,1,1),
                    "c3"=c(1,1,0,1,0),
                    "f4"=c(1,0,0,0,1),
                    "c4"=c(NA,0,0,1,0))
```

I  have 'dataHAVE' and seek to generate 'dataWANT' The rules are:

> if f1 and c1 = 0, w1 = 0
>
> if f1 = 1 and c1 = 0, w1 = 1
>
> if f1 = 0 and c1 = 1, w1 = 2
>
> if f1 = 1 and c1 = 1, w1 = 2

Basically I am wondering: how can I generate this variables and secondly, how can I execute a data.table function on dataHAVE while putting the new variables in dataWANT?

Comment: @akrun fixed, apologies thank you!!

Comment: I find some values not matching in `dataWANT` based on your logic

Comment: @akrun thanks so much in that case please follow the logic instead of the dataset I made up since i may have made a error =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
dataHAVE %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -student, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
        names_sep="(?<=[fc])(?=\\d+)") %>% 
  group_by(student, grp= str_c('w', grp)) %>% 
  transmute(w =  case_when(f %in%  0:1 & c == 1 ~ 2, 
            f == 1 & c == 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = w)
```

---

With `data.table`, we can use `fcase` (from the devel version) along with `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(dataHAVE), measure = patterns("^f", "^c"), 
  value.name = c('f', 'c'))[, w := fcase(f %in% 0:1 & c== ~ 2, 
      f == 1 & c == 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)]
dcast(dM, student ~ paste0('w', variable), value.var = 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it's kind of 'dirty' because of the two duplicate columns in dataHAVE. In order to address that I just run the command to remove the original columns twice... :D

I also changed your original dataHAVE command to create a data.table instead of data.frame to use data.table logic.

This isn't exactly elegant, but at least it works. The rest is just creating the logic rules before removing the old columns, I just included the rules you listed in your answer.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: New version that extracts dataWANT using the column names and with=FALSE. Much cleaner :)

```
library(data.table)
dataHAVE=data.table("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    "f1"=c(0,0,0,1,1),
                    "c1"=c(1,1,0,1,0),
                    "f2"=c(1,0,0,0,1),
                    "c2"=c(1,0,0,1,0),
                    "f3"=c(0,0,0,1,1),
                    "c4"=c(1,1,0,1,0),
                    "f4"=c(1,0,0,0,1),
                    "c4"=c(NA,0,0,1,0))

old_columns <- colnames(dataHAVE)[2:ncol(dataHAVE)]

dataHAVE[f1 == 0 & c1 == 0, 'w1' := 0]
dataHAVE[f1 == 1 & c1 == 0, 'w1' := 1]
dataHAVE[f1 == 0 & c1 == 1, 'w1' := 2]
dataHAVE[f1 == 1 & c1 == 1, 'w1' := 2]

keep_columns <- setdiff(colnames(dataHAVE), old_columns)

dataWANT <- dataHAVE[, keep_columns, with = FALSE]
```